# Kotlin and JavaFX: Bindings behave strangely

Tags: kotlin, javafx

I'm using JavaFX in Kotlin. I came across a strange issue, for which I'm posting a minimal example below. The issue is, if the Button is not included, then the listener doesn't print out anything.
The action for the button simply needs to access the object h in some way, and then the listener is triggered. The button doesn't need to be clicked, i.e. the action code doesn't have to be executed. It just has to be there.

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty
import javafx.event.ActionEvent
import javafx.event.EventHandler
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox
import javafx.scene.layout.Region
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.stage.Stage

fun main() {
    Application.launch(ExpRunner::class.java)
}

class ExpRunner : Application() {

    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {

        val myScene = Scene(buildView(), 400.0, 400.0)
        primaryStage.apply { title = "Strange" }
            .apply { scene = myScene }
        primaryStage.show()

    }

    fun buildView(): Region {
        val h = Holder()
        val cb = ComboBox<String>().apply { valueProperty().bindBidirectional(h.prop) }
            .apply { listOf("a", "b").forEach { items.add(it) } }
        h.prop.apply {
            addListener { _, _, v -> println("Prop value changed: $v") }
            return VBox(
                10.0,
                // If this button is not included, the listener above doesn't get triggered??
                Button("Check").apply { onAction = EventHandler<ActionEvent> { _ -> println(h.hashCode()) } },
                cb,
            )

        }
    }
}

class Holder {
    val prop = SimpleObjectProperty<String>("a")
}
```

To reproduce with the code below, just run, and then change the combo box selection. It will print out a line saying that the prop has changed.  However, if you comment out the line that adds the button to the VBox, then, on changing the combo box selection, nothing is printed out.

I'll be grateful for any explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a Kotlin programmer and I'm just trying to translate this to Java to test, but is the `return` statement in `buildView()` really supposed to be inside the `h.prop.apply()` call?

Comment: @James_D You're absolutely correct. And when I move it out of the apply, it works! Thanks. How can I give you credit for the answer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why that fixes the problem, which I believe is being caused by `h` being garbage collected. Try adding a call to `System.gc()` (e.g. via a click on the scene) and see if triggering that re-creates the issue.

Comment: This is very strangely constructed Kotlin.  There's no need to chain apply{}'s on the same object, just use a multi-line block of code.  The apply{} on h.prop is truly counter-intuitive with the return statement.  The whole thing is confusingly inside-out.  I'm sure this structure makes it harder for the OP to figure out what's not working properly.

Comment: Note you can simplify the code somewhat by doing `setOnAction { ... }` instead of `onAction = EventHandler<ActionEvent> { ... }`. That may not look as Kotlin-esque (given the direct call to a setter), but I personally think it's cleaner.

Comment: @James_D  The `return` inside the `apply{}` confused me too.  The `apply{}` function is supposed to work like a decorator, it returns the object it's called from.  It took me some searching, but I found this: https://medium.com/@belokon.roman/return-from-kotlins-lambda-411171923756 .  Essentially, the `return` inside an in-line method returns from the enclosing function.  If there had been any code in `buildView()` after that `apply{}` it would not have been executed.

Comment: @Slaw I still don't get why `setOnAction{}` works but `onAction = {}` doesn't.  It seems it can infer the type of the lambda in the function call version, but not in the other.  The function call method is even more attractive because you can leave out the `evt ->`, or the `_ ->` and just refer to `it`.

Comment: @DaveB Yeah, I don't get it either, especially since `onAction = ...` is literally compiled down to calling the setter anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bindings use weak listeners under the hood. This means that a binding will not prevent an object from being garbage collected if there are no other live references to it.

In the code you posted (which I have translated to Java below, mostly for my own benefit to understand the problem), when the `start()` method exits there is no longer a reference anywhere to the `Holder` instance, other than the bidirectional binding to the combo box's `valueProperty`. This means the `Holder` instance is eligible for garbage collection.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class ExpRunner extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var myScene = new Scene(buildView(), 400, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Strange");
        stage.setScene(myScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Region buildView() {
        var h = new Holder();
        var cb = new ComboBox<String>();
        cb.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(h.prop);
        List.of("a", "b").forEach(cb.getItems()::add);
        h.prop.addListener((obs, old, v) -> System.out.printf("Value changed: %s%n", v));
        return new VBox(10, cb);
    }

    static class Holder {
        ObjectProperty<String> prop = new SimpleObjectProperty<>("a");
    }
}
```

(It is possible this does not re-create the issue on all platforms. If running it produces the output from the listener on `h.prop`, add `myScene.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.gc());`. Then clicking on an empty part of the scene should force the listener to stop being invoked.)

However, when you create the button with its action listener, that button has a reference to the `Holder`. The button is referenced by its parent (the `VBox`), which is referenced by the `Scene`, which in turn is referenced by the `Stage` to which a reference exists beyond the scope of `start()`. So the button (and specifically its action listener) prevent the `Holder` from being garbage collected, and its listener is invoked.

A more natural fix is to create a reference to the `Holder` outside the `start()` method:

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.List;

public class ExpRunner extends Application {

    private Holder h;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var myScene = new Scene(buildView(), 400, 400);
        stage.setTitle("Strange");
        stage.setScene(myScene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private Region buildView() {
        h = new Holder();
        var cb = new ComboBox<String>();
        cb.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(h.prop);
        List.of("a", "b").forEach(cb.getItems()::add);
        h.prop.addListener((obs, old, v) -> System.out.printf("Value changed: %s%n", v));
        return new VBox(10, cb);
    }

    static class Holder {
        ObjectProperty<String> prop = new SimpleObjectProperty<>("a");
    }
}
```

Note that in most applications, any listener you are likely to register with this `Holder` object will likely be referenced either elements in a model that persists (if you use some kind of MVC-like design) or indirectly by the scene graph. So in most real cases this premature garbage collection is unlikely to happen. However, it is worth being aware of why this occurs.

Comment: Spot on! I tried your suggestion with adding a call to System.gc() and the behaviour was exactly what you anticipated; it stopped the listener from being activated. Thanks for explaining what was very mystifying to me.